Autodistill GroundedSAM stuck on labeling first image?
I am trying to label a dataset of 200,000 images of airplanes. I am usinging autodistill and GroundedSAM to try and do the tast. It has been stuck on 0/219670 for a while now and at 0it/s
Here is my code:
from autodistill_grounded_sam import GroundedSAM
from autodistill.detection import CaptionOntology
from autodistill_yolov8 import YOLOv8

image_dir = r'C:\Users\Colter\Desktop\plane_detector\dataset\all_images'
base_model = GroundedSAM(ontology=CaptionOntology({"Airplane": "Plane"}))
base_model.label(image_dir, extension=".jpg")

And my output is in the image attached: 
I was hoping for the progress bar to slowly increase and for the program to label all my images and where the aircraft in the picture was, however it's stuck on 0.

submit bug to authors of library? -- is that a [mre]? I see no use of YOLOv8 after the import
